# Overwrite files when downloading via Download Manager

Tags: java, android, android-download-manager

I cannot find out how to do this. I uses to download with asycntask. When I did that, it would always overwrite the file when downloading. Now, when I switched to Download Manager, it will download the file with the same file name, except with a number next to it(ex. dl-1.zip). It is very important I overwrite the files when downloading. How could I do this?

Comment: when you're submitting the file to the download manager check if the file already exists. then delete it.