# Android DownloadManager never returns ERROR_FILE_ALREADY_EXISTS

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I am using [DonwloadManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) in my project, in the official reference there is description about [ERROR_FILE_ALREADY_EXISTS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html#ERROR_FILE_ALREADY_EXISTS). 
The problem is that I never get this error while using the same URL and Destination URI. `DownloadManager` is always downloads the same file, just adds some number at the end of the file name so it will be different from the previous download.

The enqueue code is really simple and working great, except this weird thing that allows you to re-download already downloaded file:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
Request request = new Request(uri);
request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE |
DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI);
request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(false);
Uri fileDestinationUri = Uri.parse("file://" + new File(destinationFilePath);
request.setDestinationUri(fileDestinationUri);
long downloadId = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

I have a `BroadcastReciever` which is listening to `android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE` intent:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

    long downloadId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1);

    Query query = new Query();
    query.setFilterById(downloadId);
    Cursor cur = dm.query(query);

    if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
        int columnIndex = cur.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);

        switch (cur.getInt(columnIndex)) {
            case DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL:
                Log.d(Settings.TAG_APP, "Download successfully completed.");
            break;

            case DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED:
                int columnReasonIndex = cur.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_REASON);
                Log.d(Settings.TAG_APP, "Download failed with error: " + cur.getInt(columnReasonIndex));
            break;
        }

    }

    cur.close();
    cur = null;
}
```

I found another 2 questions that somehow connects to my question, but without answers as well :
[Android - Overwrite files when downloading via Download Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15961936/android-overwrite-files-when-downloading-via-download-manager)
[How can i make download manager overwrite an exisiting file instead of renaming the file in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14362659/how-can-i-make-download-manager-overwrite-an-exisiting-file-instead-of-renaming)

Comment: Where are you using `DownloadManager.query()` to (hopefully) see the error returned?

Comment: @Geobits I updated the question, posted the code of the receiver. Please take a look.